# How are PCRs Checked and are external TPMs vulnerable to hardware attack

Tags: tpm

Are boot measurements checked against PCRs by the TPM, or is the PCR is reported and the measuring software does the check?

Since the PCR validation enables the release of some secrets in the TPM, I guess it must be done by the TPM.  So what is to stop me from spying on the reported measurements written to the TPM on the LPC bus, then spoofing that communication later?

Is this a realistic attack vector?

Answer (score 1):

Measurements are taken by software, then extended into the PCRs held by the TPM. The TPM can enforce restrictions on who and when can extend and reset which PCRs (though this is pretty much set in advance, per the table section 3.1 in [TPM 1.2 spec part 1](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/PC-Client-Implementation-for-BIOS.pdf)). Those PCRs can be read by pretty much any user on the platform, and seen on the LPC bus.

The TPM doesn't perform any *validation* on PCRs--the measurements extended into PCRs and the order in which they are extended is up to the software performing the measurements.

The TPM *uses* the PCRs for a variety of lockdown functions (e.g. securing data through a seal or bind operation). When the PCRs are used in this way, the TPM uses its own PCR storage, as opposed to receiving the values over the LPC bus. When PCRs are provided for remote attestation, the PCRs are accompanied by a TPM quote, which is a signature of the PCRs made with a key that only the TPM can use for signing. If PCR values are manipulated in any way, this manipulation can be easily discovered. There are really no opportunities to use spoofed data to gain access to secured data.

If an attacker has access to the LPC bus, a denial of service might be possible by spoofing a locality to extend data into a PCR used to secure data. In most cases, only the expected PCR values can be used to retrieve PCR-secured data. By extending a PCR used for this function, the value would change from the expected value.